# how to set up dynamic partition where the column keys will be the partitions

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, dynamic, hive, partition

So I have a table A and table B, where table A data was inserted from table B.
essentially table A is same as table B, only difference is that table A has a date_partition column where table B does not have. 
the table A schema is as such:
ID int
school_bg_dt string
log_on_count int
active_count int

table B schema is: 
ID int
school_bg_dt bigint
log_on_count int
active_count int
date_partition string

here is my query of inserting table B to table A which have an error I coudlnt figure out:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE A PARTITION(date_partition=school_bg_dt)
SELECT ID, cast(school_bg_dt as BIGINT), log_on_count, active_count FROM table
B;
```

However, I got error that the inpurt does not recognize operation near the date_partition..
not sure whats to do here, please help... 
so the design it is to make each school_bg_dt key as a partition as it has many unique data with that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts):

> In the dynamic partition inserts, users can give partial partition specifications, which means just specifying the list of partition column names in the PARTITION clause. The column values are optional. If a partition column value is given, we call this a static partition, otherwise it is a dynamic partition. Each dynamic partition column has a corresponding input column from the select statement. This means that the dynamic partition creation is determined by the value of the input column. The dynamic partition columns must be specified last among the columns in the SELECT statement and in the same order in which they appear in the PARTITION() clause.

So, try:

```
FROM B
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE A PARTITION(date_partition)
SELECT ID, cast(school_bg_dt as BIGINT), log_on_count, active_count, school_bg_dt as date_partition;
```

Also, note that if you're creating many partitions, you should update the following conf settings:

- hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode -  Maximum number of dynamic
  partitions allowed to be created in each mapper/reducer node (default = 100)
- hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions - Maximum number of dynamic
  partitions allowed to be created in total (default = 1000)
- hive.exec.max.created.files - Maximum number of HDFS files created by all mappers/reducers in a MapReduce job (default = 100000)

Comment: Thank you Alex, but it failed, it says execution error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: @Michelle Please try using the new syntax after the edit

Comment: Alex, it did not work still, the conf setting expect INT type but my partition column needs a type of String

Comment: @Michelle yes, the conf settings expect ints, it has nothing to do with the partitions type... How many partitions do you create? how many distinct school_bg_dt values are in table b?

Comment: Alex, I ended up to partition it by yearly, like set the date_partition to a year value and that worked. I think maybe the server cannot process large amount of partitions. The partitions was set to monthly and we needed it for 5 years of data, that is a lot of data to process.. but for now we just decided to use year instead of month.